# how can Change target from tinyscrollbar to body when reaches top/end of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, tinyscrollbar

I am trying to implement tiny-scrollbar into my website and, i want to change target from tiny-scrollbar to body when it reaches top or end of body, how can i do this,please help.

Comment: well i tried to make tinyscroll bar scroll proportion to body scroll size but now its only shows content upto window hight bellow that blank.  following is my jquery :

Comment: var heightscroll = $(window).height();
 $('.viewport').css('height', heightscroll-270);              
  var oScrollbar = $('.scrollbar1');
  oScrollbar.tinyscrollbar();
   oScrollbar.tinyscrollbar_update();

Comment: please provide some code examples of what you have tried your self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not able to understand your question completely...but is this what you want?
[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6A6qy/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var ScrollTop = parseInt($(window).scrollTop());
        console.log(ScrollTop);

        if (ScrollTop == 0) {
            alert("i just hit the t0p");
        }
        else if(ScrollTop == 1574){
          alert("i just hit the bottom");        
        }
    });
});
```

UPDATE:
[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TLkmK/9/)

Just use console log to check the scrollTop and give your conditions accordingly.Hopw this helpps

Comment: i have one div where i applied tiny-scrollbar , when i scroll down in tiny-scrollbar and hit the bottom of page , i can not see content of that div bellow the body hight as body scroll don't move automatically , hence i want some code to move that document scroll .

Comment: actually i am new to jquery and i dont know how to fire event when i scroll  tinyscrollbar it will be grateful if you give me code which fires on tinyscrollbar scroll event. thanks for your replies